# Delay for overlay to disappear on mouseout

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, delay, mouseout

I've got a site with an instance of WooCommerce running on it. On the Product Archive page there's a noticeable delay when the mouse leaves a product and the overlay disappearing. I'd like to reduce that delay to about 0.1s

URL: http://economistfoundation.org/the-library/

I've tried looking through the various CSS files in the main theme and the woocommerce plugin to see if there's a 'transition' with 0.5s or similar that controls .thumb-overlay, but can't find anything that seems relevant.

I wondered if the setting might be in Javascript, but there are so many files where it might be stored I'm at a loss.

I've looked at the page using the Firebug inspector and .thumb-overlay has a style attribute that moves between 'display: block' and 'display: none', and as you move the mouse over an attribute of 'opacity' rapidly counts from 0 to 1.

Does anyone know where the delay value might be stored?

Comment: This is definitely a Javascript issue. I wonder if there is a settings page for the plugin that provides this functionality where you can change it there? Rather than editing the plugin's code directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in your `wp-content/themes/agent/woocommerce/woocommerce-custom.js` file at **line 19**.

```
    jQuery(document).on( 'mouseenter', '.products .product', function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.thumb-overlay').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    });
    jQuery(document).on( 'mouseleave', '.products .product', function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.thumb-overlay').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    });
```

**EDITED**

Child themes only override files in the main theme directory (like header.php) that are called in with functions like get_template_part or get_header, etc.

The correct way to add scripts to WordPress is with [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).  If your parent theme uses this, you can override the JS files by using [wp_dequeue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) and enqueuing your own.

Like so...

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so28089698_script_fix' );
function so28089698_script_fix()
{
    wp_dequeue_script( 'parent_theme_script_handle' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'child_theme_script_handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/yourjs.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

If the parent theme isn't using wp_enqueue_script, it's probably hooking into wp_head (or wp_footer) to echo out the scripts there.  So you'd use [remove_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) to get rid of those functions echoing the scripts out, and then enqueue your own script.

If the script is hard coded into the template file, you'll just need to replace that template file in your child theme without the script tag.

If they used wp_enqueue_script calls that utilize [get_stylesheet_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), then you shouldn't have to do anything.  Since this isn't happening, you'll just have to poke around and see what the theme author did.

Comment: Thanks – I've stuck 50 into the brackets after fadeIn and fadeOut and it works perfectly!
To add this to my child theme, do I need to exactly recreate the pathway, (ie wp-content/themes/agent-child/woocommerce/woocommerce-custom.js) and create a js file with the modified code into that? Or do I need to create a fresh javascript file and register and enqueue it through functions.php?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry I did not get you ... What do you want to do ?

Comment: "Voteup requires 15 reputation"
As soon as I have the ability I'll be back to upvote you!

Comment: Are you using child theme ?

Comment: Yup. Do I add this code to a new js file in /agent-child/js/, and then add the register and enqueue code to my /agent-child/functions.php? Then call it in a new child version of the 'archive-product.php'?